# HTML span change data with Javascript and add time duration for questions change?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML span change data with jquery and add time duration for questions change?
I am trying to change HTML text with jquery with certain time durations

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sets = $(".set")
var set = sets[0], quote = 0;

sets.hide();

$(sets[0]).fadeIn(1500);

function showQuote() {
    if($(set).children().eq(quote).is(':last-child')) {
        if($(set).hasClass("last")) {
            set = $(".set").first();
        } else {
            set = $(set).next();
        }
        sets.hide();
        $(set).fadeIn(1500);
        quote = 1;
    } else {
        ++quote
    }

    $(set).children().eq(quote)
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(1000, showQuote);
}

showQuote();
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-how" style="">
                <div class="col-xl-12 bg-banner-text text-center" style="padding-top:3%;">
                    <h1 style="font-size:36pxx !important;" class="sec1-head set">How do we do it?<br/>
                        <span style="" class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Ethical and Humanizing AI</span>
                        <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Redefine professional and academic achievement</span>
                        <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Create a data driven Soft-Skills resume</span>
                    </h1>
                    <h1 style="font-size:36pxx !important;" class="sec1-head set last">Curating Experiences for Credentials<br/>
                        <span style="" class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">School</span>
                        <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Work</span>
                        <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Internships</span>
                        <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Apprenticeship</span>
                        <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Workshops</span>
                        <span style="display: none;"  class="quotes sec1-head-quotes">Co-Curricular Activities</span>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```